# Multiple routes , and dynamic Asp.net mvc pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Im getting dynamically Url from database, and pass it into Multiple routes by 1 controller. And when put content body of url-items to the model of View. **And the point is, that the  new page start loading only after compiled EDITED project.Before it just showed 404 page.**

```
public class DynamicController : MenuController
{
    //
    // GET: /Dynamic/
   s

    public  ActionResult Indexx(string routes) {
        var str = service.Get().Single(x=>x.Url==routes);

        return View(str);
    }


}
```

Routes:

```
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
      /**/  IMenuService<Menu> service = new MenuEntityService();
      foreach (var item in service.Get())
      {
          routes.MapRoute(
          name: item.Url,
          url: item.Url,
          defaults: new { controller = "Dynamic", action = "Indexx",routes=item.Url },
          namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication1.Controllers" }
          );
      }
```

Comment: How can i fix that ?)

Answer (score 0):

Registering of routes only occurs at the `Application_Start` event. This event only occurs once during the life-cycle of your application.

So your application pool would need to be restarted in order to create the route for each of the dynamic paths that have been created. (Hence why after the recompile/deploy the routes work, as the App Pool gets restarted automatically)

To avoid the need to restart the Application Pool each time a new dynamic path is created, the better option would be to create a catch all/default route to handle these dynamic pages

```
//this catches all  requests
routes.MapRoute(
    "Dynamic page route",
    "{*routes}",
     new { controller = "Dynamic", action = "Indexx" } 
);
```

Comment: dude how can i restard this pool, plz tell me. This question simply blows my mind..

Comment: @TimurShahbanov To manually restart the application pool, go to IIS > Application Pools find the Application Pool associated with your site, right click on it and select Restart. To avoid restarting the Application Pool altogether, the catch-all route would be the best solution.

Comment: Its not working, im losing my content body if dont give a parameters to Indexx method and render it to the View.

Comment: @TimurShahbanov I have adjusted my answer slightly, the catch-all just needs to be given the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answear with this :`HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` i wrote it in my controller action who create menu item